# strange copy constructor behavior in inherit tree

Tags: c++

i have three class types: Base->Center->Child, and i want to make it posible to construct child type from parent type, so i declared them like this:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(void) {cout << "Base()" << endl;}
    virtual ~Base(void) {}
    Base(const Base &ref) {cout << "Base(const Base &)" << endl;}
};
class Center : public virtual Base {
public:
    Center(void) : Base() {cout << "Center()" << endl;}
    Center(const Base &ref) : Base(ref) {cout << "Center(const Base &)" << endl;}
};
class Child : public virtual Center {
public:
    Child(void) : Center() {cout << "Child()" << endl;}
    Child(const Base &ref) : Center(ref) {cout << "Child(const Base &)" << endl;}
};
```

it's OK to call it like this: (calling Center and Base's copy constructor)

```
Base base;
Center center(base);
```

.
however, these code act unexpectly:

```
Child child(base);
```

the output is:

```
Base()
Center(const Base &)
Child(const Base &)
```

why called Base(void) instead of Base(const Base &)?

**SOLVED** (many thanks to Dietmar Kühl and Adam Burry)
two method:

```
1. add Base(const Base &) to Child, which would looks like this:
   Child(const Base &ref) : Base(ref), Center(ref) {}
2. or, remove virtual inheritance, which would looks like this:
   class Center : public Base {...}
   class Child : public Center {...}
```

Comment: Do you know the order because you added some `cout << ...` statements? Could you show them?

Comment: i debug it by break point, question updated with cout

Comment: BTW, compiled with XCode and running at iPhone 6.1 simulator, i've no idea whether it matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to a `virtual` base class is provided by the most derived class, not by an intermediate class. If you want to pass the argument you received for `Child` to the `Base`, you need to implement your `Child` constructor like this:

```
Child::Child(Base const& other)
    : Base(other)
    , Center(other)
{
}
```

BTW, it is unusual to use `(void)` instead of `()` to indicate that the function doesn't take any arguments in C++: the `void` was at some point necessary in C to distinguish between a variable argument list function and a function taking no argument (I don't know if this is still the case in C11). In C++ an empty pair of parenthesis always indicated an empty argument list.

Comment: The `ctor(void)` convention is used by the Visual Studio code generator. I have no idea why.

Comment: it works! but still confused, why Base(other) called by Center(other) have no effect? if there's a GrandChild inherit from Child, is it also necessary to call "Base, Center, Child" in GrandChild? that's quite unconvenient :(

Comment: If you remove the `virtual` keyword you will get the behaviour you expect. Otherwise see this FAQ for more info: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-inheritance-ctors.html